# List(Of T) groupby visual basic

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps

i want to Group Movies in gridview by category. i have C# code and i want to convert it to Visual Basic.

```
var moviesByCategories = movies.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
            .Select(x => new MovieCategory { Title = x.Key, Items = x.ToList() });
```

i tried the following code but it gives me an error.

```
Dim query = From film In movies Group film.Title By Category = film.Category Into grpTitle = Group
```

UPDATE 
used converter.telerik.com suggested by Plutonix

```
Dim moviesByCategories = movies.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Category).[Select](Function(x) New MovieCategory() With { _
Key .Title = x.Key, _
Key .Items = x.ToList() _
})
```

But the code doesn't work gives the following error
[image]

My classes
1. MoviePageViewModel

```
Public Class MoviesPageViewModel
    Private _Items As List(Of MovieCategory)
    Public Property Items() As List(Of MovieCategory)
        Get
            Return _Items
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of MovieCategory))
            _Items = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()
        Dim movies As List(Of Movie) = New List(Of Movie)
       'adding movies to movies list
        Dim moviesByCategories = movies.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Category).[Select](Function(x) New MovieCategory() With { _
Key .Title = x.Key, _
Key .Items = x.ToList() _
 })
        Items = moviesByCategories
    End Sub
End Class
```

2.Movie class

```
Public Class Movie
    Private _Title As String
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Title = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Subtitle As String
    Public Property Subtitle() As String
        Get
            Return _Subtitle
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Subtitle = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Image As String
    Public Property Image() As String
        Get
            Return _Image
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Image = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Category As String
    Public Property Category() As String
        Get
            Return _Category
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Category = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Sub New(title As String, category As String, subtitle As String, img As String)
        _Title = title
        _Subtitle = subtitle
        _Image = img
        _Category = category
    End Sub
End Class
```

3. MovieCategory

   ```
   Public Class MovieCategory
   Private _Title As String
   Public Property Title() As String
       Get
           Return _Title
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As String)
           _Title = value
       End Set
   End Property
   Private _Items As List(Of Movie)
   Public Property Items() As List(Of Movie)
       Get
           Return _Items
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As List(Of Movie))
           _Items = value
       End Set
   End Property

     End Class
   ```

   UPDATE 
   now i get this error after using the code provided by Tom
   [image]

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: post the conversion as an answer

Comment: @Plutonix The converted code doesn't work, gives an error.

Comment: Also Jay_P, you might want to include more information when asking questions. For instance: "I tried the following code but it gives me an error." isn't very helpful. What error does it give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query syntax (which i prefer in VB.NET):

```
Dim query = From movy In movies
    Group By category = movy.Category Into MovyCategoryGroup = Group
    Select New MovieCategory With {
        .Title = category,
        .Items = MovyCategoryGroup.ToList()
    }
```

Method syntax:

```
Dim query = movies.GroupBy(Function(m) m.Category).
    Select(Function(g) New MovieCategory With {
        .Title = g.Key,
        .Items = g.ToList()
    })
```

Comment: your code gives the following error `Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[VB$AnonymousType_
0`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ConsoleApplication1.M
odule1+Movie]],ConsoleApplication1.Module1+MovieCategory]' to type 'System.Colle
ctions.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.Module1+MovieCategory]'.
`

Comment: @Jay_P: i don't know where you get that exception. The query itself works. I have tested it with your classes. However, i have edited my answer to show also method syntax.

Comment: thanks it's working i was missing `ToList` at the end of my code.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the "key" came from in the conversion, this is proper VB code:

```
Dim moviesByCategories = movies.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Category)
                               .Select(Function(x) New MovieCategory() With {.Title = x.Key,
                                                                             .Items = x.ToList()}
```

Comment: You can use `Key` in anonymous types to specify which columns should be used for `GetHashCode` and `Equals`(as opposed to C# where all colunmns are used). MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx So the converter mistakenly assumed that it's an anonymous type.