# How to GroupBy a List(of object) in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, group-by

Before I asked this similar question for C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097071/loop-through-a-list-and-combine-totals-where-an-identifier-is-the-same). I am now trying to copy that into VB.

I have a class for variations in my code like this:

```
 Public Class TariffVariations
    Public Property TariffCode() As String
        Get
            Return m_TariffCode
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_TariffCode = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TariffCode As String

    Public Property Eye() As String
        Get
            Return m_Eye
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Eye = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Eye As String

    Public Property Count() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Count
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Count = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Count As Integer
End Class
```

And I am looping through a repeater to build this List of Variations up. I have 8 objects in my list, 4 variations for each eye. 
I am now trying to loop through that list and count the times that item is selected, hence the count.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090835/listof-t-groupby-visual-basic) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121303/how-to-use-groupby-to-group-over-multiple-columns-with-vb-net) for examples of what to do with the Group by. I have also converted my code from C# from my previous question to VB.

I have ended up with these two samples suited to my code. Please excuse the naming conventions:

```
    Dim lstNew = lstObjs.GroupBy(Function(c) c.TariffCode).Select(Function(c) New TariffVariations() With {.Eye = c.Key})

        Dim newCarList = lstObjs.GroupBy(Function(c) New With { _
 c.Eye, _
 c.TariffCode _
}).[Select](Function(carGroup) New TariffVariations() With { _
  .Eye = carGroup.Key.Eye, _
  .TariffCode = carGroup.Key.TariffCode, _
  .Count = carGroup.Sum(Function(c) c.Count) _
}).ToList()
```

Now in both those lists, instead of them collapsing to just 2 objects each for eyes Left and Right with the same code and count, instead keep the 8 from the list that is being grouped.

How can I sort through these lists properly? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After obtaining my list, i use the following to get the values I want:

```
     Dim lst = From item In lstObjs
               Order By item.TariffCode, item.Eye
               Group By item.TariffCode, item.Eye
               Into grp = Group, Sum(item.Count)
               Order By TariffCode, Eye
               Select Sum

     Dim canCont As Boolean = True

     For Each num As Integer In lst
        If num > 1 Then
           canCont = False
        End If
     Next
```

Which works for me